# Does "made his point to" in this sentence mean "made his way to"?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> Our fox **made his point to** Moorhill.

Comment: You are gonna have to give more context than that, what are you trying say here? To make his point  means to get your point across, it does not mean 'make his way to'. 'make his way to' means coming somewhre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very specialised use of *point*. In hunting it is ‘a spot to which a straight run is made’ or ‘a straight run across country between two such spots’. It can apply to either the hunters or, as here, the hunted.

The word also occurs in a particular kind of equestrian event known as a *point-to-point*.

Comment: This [John Peel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Peel_\(writer\))?

Comment: @kiamlaluno No, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Peel_(huntsman)) John Peel.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the meaning of "make" in the sentence? I can't quite understand its meaning here. Also, "Moorhill" is a place, right?

Comment: @Dragon Buster. It means he reached the point he was going to, or possibly that he was on his way to it. Yes, Moorhill will be a place.